# Flutter SwitchListTile Flag as Zero false One true - Allow One Switch flag at a time to be set to true

Tags: flutter

I need to use bool flag Zero for False and One for True to switch.

Issue: I can set any flag to True.
My Goal: Allow One Switch flag at a time to be set to true.

I asked similar question before, but I was using bool flag.
I will be using SQFLite to save a switch selection(later on).
SQFLite does not allow to save a bool flag. Therefore, I can only save int Zero and int One(zero means false and one true).

In the code below, the function boolSelectedFlagValue() is changing bool to int.

Could you please advise how to fix this code. Thank You

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {runApp(MyApp());}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class DataModel{
  int id;
  String name;
  bool isSelected;
  DataModel({required this.id, required this.name, this.isSelected = false});
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final List<DataModel> names = <DataModel>[];
  TextEditingController mc = TextEditingController();

  addItemToList() {setState(() {if (mc.text.isNotEmpty) {names.add(DataModel(id:names.length+1, name:mc.text,));}});}
  bool boolSelectedFlagValue(){return names[index].isSelected  == 1 ? true : false;}

  int index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget space = SizedBox(width: 100, height: 5, child: Text(""));
    Widget myinput = TextField(controller: mc,decoration:InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Name'));
    Widget btnAdd = ElevatedButton(onPressed: addItemToList, child: Text('Add'));
    Widget mylist = SizedBox(width: 800,height: 500,child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: names.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                SwitchListTile(
                    title: Text(names[index].name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
                    value: boolSelectedFlagValue(),
                    onChanged: (bool value) {
                      {
                        names.forEach((fl)=>fl.isSelected=false);
                        setState(() {
                          boolSelectedFlagValue() == value;
                          mc.text=names[index].name;
                        });
                      };
                    })
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );

    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,body: SingleChildScrollView(scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,children: <Widget>[
              Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,children: <Widget>[space,myinput,space,btnAdd,space,mylist,space])))]))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your dataModel you are using bool `bool isSelected`, operand doesn't work on different dataTypes.

So you can convert the model class like:

```
class DataModel {// i prefer final with const constructor
  int id;
  String name;
  int isSelected;
  DataModel({required this.id, required this.name, this.isSelected = 0});
}
```

And SwitchLIstTile

```dart
SwitchListTile(
  title:
      Text(names[index].name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
  value: names[index].isSelected == 1,
  onChanged: (bool value) {
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        if (i == index) continue;
        names[i].isSelected = 0;
      }
      names[index].isSelected = value ? 1 : 0;
      setState(() {});
    }
    ;
  })
```

Also I am thinking about RadioGroup for your case.